# Maximum number of node in a binary tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Given binary tree having `L` leaf nodes, what will be maximum number of node in that tree? No additional information of the tree type.

Comment: so I guess this is homework? - Can you try to explain what "maximum" you are talking about?

Comment: What is maximum?
Maximum value? Maximum no. of nodes already there? OR Total maximum no. of nodes that can be added?

Comment: @CarstenKönig Maximum ,means maximum number of node sorry for putting ambiguous statement.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a full binary tree, the total number of nodes is equal to (2*L - 1).

Comment: I think you are wrong.
Suppose the tree is level 1 = [1] , level2= [2,3] , level3=[4,5,6,7]
Then the no. of leaf nodes are 4.

Now suppose in the above tree only one more node is added at level4=[8] 
Then also no. of leaf nodes are 4 but maximum nodes are different in both cases

Comment: @AyushJain I think his formula is right ,if u consider the definition of full binary tree then it is tree whose node contains either two child or none(zero) child.@mathdan my question was nothing has been said about tree type.

Comment: If we make absolutely no assumptions except that each node can have *at most* two children, then there is no upper limit (you can extend any leaf with an arbitrarily long chain of nodes w/ one child each). So, for a finite answer, some kind of restriction must be made. (Different restrictions will lead to different answers.)

Answer (score 0):

For a full tree (meaning each node has either 0 or 2 children) the solution is `2L-1` as said by @mathdan. However if the tree is not full, the answer is actually infinite, easy to prove in an example (`L=1`):

```
root
  \
  node1
    \
    node2
      \
      ...
        \
        nodeXYZ
          \
          leaf
```

If you decide for a concrete number of nodes `N` then you can easily include an additional node in the structure, making your claim of `N` nodes invalid.